# Looping on a javascript data set

Tags: javascript, json, loops, plugins

i don't really know how to google about this issue exactly, so i thought i might ask here.

i wanted to draw an arc from a given longitude, latitude of an origin to the destination. i have already prepared them in a variable. but i don't know how to set the loop on the plugin provided. here is the sample plugin page i used: http://jsbin.com/nutawiboci/1/edit?html,output

and the following image is my attempt to loop through my data over the plugin. the output only draws one arc(assuming the last[from the loop] only).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTbu7.jpg

Thank you for taking the time...!

Answer (score 0):

your map.arc(), it's always destroy the last map.arc() when you looping, then you just get the last one.

the structure must be like this

```
map.arc([
   {
    origin: {
        latitude: 40.639722,
        longitude: 73.778889
    },
    destination: {
        latitude: 37.618889,
        longitude: -122.375
    }
  },
  {
      origin: {
          latitude: 30.194444,
          longitude: -97.67
      },
      destination: {
          latitude: 25.793333,
          longitude: -0.290556
      }
  }
  ], {strokeWidth: 2});
```

in your code its like this

```
map.arc([
   {
    origin: {
        latitude: 40.639722,
        longitude: 73.778889
    },
    destination: {
        latitude: 37.618889,
        longitude: -122.375
    }
  },
  {
      origin: {
          latitude: 30.194444,
          longitude: -97.67
      },
      destination: {
          latitude: 25.793333,
          longitude: -0.290556
      }
  }
  ], {strokeWidth: 2});map.arc([
   {
    origin: {
        latitude: 40.639722,
        longitude: 73.778889
    },
    destination: {
        latitude: 37.618889,
        longitude: -122.375
    }
  },
  {
      origin: {
          latitude: 30.194444,
          longitude: -97.67
      },
      destination: {
          latitude: 25.793333,
          longitude: -0.290556
      }
  }
  ], {strokeWidth: 2});
```

Comment: yes, i know that. but i don't know how to do it like the first one in a loop. i was hoping you'd show me the code on how to do it as the first one with a loop.

Comment: how about this **_`for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
var origin_long[] = data[i][0][0];
var origin_lat[] = data[i][0][1];

var destination_long[] = data[i][1][0];
var destination_lat[] = data[i][1][1];
}

map.arc(
[
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
{
 origin:
 {
 latitude:origin_lat[i],
 longitude:origin_long[i]
 },
 destination:
 {
 latitude:destination_lat[i],
 longitude:destination_long[i]
 }
}
}
], {strokeWidth:2});`_** sorry idk how to write code in comment

Comment: it shows same syntax error like before: **SyntaxError: missing variable name**

Comment: _for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){_